# Tikz force node in specific layers in layered graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, layout

I'm trying to use layered graph layouts to generate Directed Acyclic Graphs where all nodes are partitioned into layers. The following code produces a near-perfect result.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners]
\graph [layered layout,
edge quotes={fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize},
nodes={circle,draw,inner sep=.2,outer sep=0, minimum size=.45cm},
level sep=1.5cm, %vertical distance between layers
sibling distance=2cm, %distance between nodes of the same connected component in the same layer
component sep=0cm %distance between connected components
]
{
{
[nodes={draw=none,text opacity=0}, edge={draw=none}]
l0 ->["$v0$"] l1 ->["$v1$"] l2 ->["$v2$"] l3 ->["$v4$"] l4 ->["$v5$"] l5;
},
{[edge={pos=.45}]
r/"$r$";
t/"$t$";
2/"$u_{2}$";
3/"$u_{3}$";
4/"$u_{4}$";
5/"$u_{5}$";
6/"$u_{6}$";
7/"$u_{7}$";
8/"$u_{8}$";
9/"$u_{9}$";
10/"$u_{10}$";
11/"$u_{11}$";
12/"$u_{12}$";
r ->["$0$",bend left=0] 2,
r ->["$1$",bend left=0] 3,
2 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 4,
2 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 5,
3 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 6,
3 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 4,
4 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 7,
4 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 8,
5 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 9,
5 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 7,
6 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 8,
6 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 9,
7 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 10,
7 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 11,
8 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 12,
8 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 10,
9 ->["$0$",bend left=0] 11,
9 ->["$1$",bend left=0] 12,
10 ->["$1$",bend left=-80] t,
10 ->["$4$",bend left=-60] t,
10 ->["$7$",bend left=-40] t,
10 ->["$10$",bend left=-20] t,
10 ->["$13$",bend left=0] t,
10 ->["$16$",bend left=20] t,
10 ->["$19$",bend left=40] t,
10 ->["$22$",bend left=60] t,
10 ->["$25$",bend left=80] t,
11 ->["$0$",bend left=-80] t,
11 ->["$3$",bend left=-60] t,
11 ->["$6$",bend left=-40] t,
11 ->["$9$",bend left=-20] t,
11 ->["$12$",bend left=0] t,
11 ->["$15$",bend left=20] t,
11 ->["$18$",bend left=40] t,
11 ->["$21$",bend left=60] t,
11 ->["$24$",bend left=80] t,
12 ->["$2$",bend left=-80] t,
12 ->["$5$",bend left=-60] t,
12 ->["$8$",bend left=-40] t,
12 ->["$11$",bend left=-20] t,
12 ->["$14$",bend left=0] t,
12 ->["$17$",bend left=20] t,
12 ->["$20$",bend left=40] t,
12 ->["$23$",bend left=60] t,
}
};
\begin{scope}[node distance=.4cm,font=\scriptsize]
\node[right of=r]{$0$};
\node[right of=t]{$1$};
\node[right of=2]{$0$};
\node[right of=3]{$2$};
\node[right of=4]{$0$};
\node[right of=5]{$1$};
\node[right of=6]{$2$};
\node[right of=7]{$0$};
\node[right of=8]{$2$};
\node[right of=9]{$1$};
\node[right of=10]{$0$};
\node[right of=11]{$1$};
\node[right of=12]{$2$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{c0(mod5)}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{test 0}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that for some weird reason, vertex t is placed in the same layer as u7, u8, u9, resulting in a lot of edge overlap. Vertex t should have been placed in a new layer, below the layer containing vertices u10, u11, u12. Is there a way I can force this?

According to the Tikz [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) chapter 31st, the layered layout algorithm performs the following steps:

1. Cycle removal.
2. Layer assignment (sometimes called node ranking).
3. Crossing minimization (also referred to as node ordering).
4. Node positioning (or coordinate assignment).
5. Edge routing.

Technically I don't need steps 1,2,5 because I already know the layers for each node, and my graph is guaranteed not to contain cycles. I do however need step 3 to determine the ordering of nodes in each layer to minimize crossings, as well as step 4 to determine coordinates.

Comment: This is at best a workaround but if you replace `10 ->["$1$",bend left=-80] t,` by `10 ->["$1$",bend left=-80] t[nudge=(down:4.5cm)],` you can "nudge" `t` down.

Comment: The issue is caused by bugs in `layered layout`. (1) an easy fix would be to set the node ranking algorithm to `minimum height layer assignment` as opposed to the default `linear optimization layer assignment`. However, the `minimum height layer assignment` is bugged because `NodeRankingMinimumHeight.lua line 31` should be `for _,edge in ipairs(edges) do` as opposed to `for _,edge in ipairs(edge) do`. (2) even after fixing this, there's another bug. Somehow the number of incoming edges into vertex `t` appears to be 0 in `NodeRankingMinimumHeight.lua`! Need to figure out how to file bug report.

Comment: The 2nd issue is caused by a bug in node:getIncomingEdges() which is invoked in NodeRankingMinimumHeight.lua. For vertex t, the set of incoming edges is empty. This seems to be caused by the lines `r/"$r$"; t/"$t$"; ...`. Removing those lines fixes the issue. Clearly you loose the node labels. Any workarounds? Bug reported: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/525/